# Why can't we write public boolean onClick(View v) like we write public boolean onLongClick(View v)

Tags: android, android-fragments

When we write the method for Long Click we write as -

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v){

    return true;
}
```

I know the reason behind why we write it as boolean, my query is why can't we also write

```
public boolean onClick(View v){

    return true;
}
```

why does making onCLick a Boolean give me an error?

Answer (score 1):

because the onClick method doesn't return any value. You don't need to write return operator for the onClick method.